# Get relationship 2 tables deep in MySQL

Tags: mysql, join, group-by, count, left-join

I have the following tables:

- projects (id)
- items (project_id)
- comments (item_id)

I want to:

1. count all the items in a project
2. count all the comments in a project.

For #1, I am doing the following:

```
SELECT 
    p.*,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM items WHERE project_id=p.id) items_count,
FROM projects p
```

How can I go one level deeper and count the comments?

Comment: Please share the schema of all the tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `id` is the primary key of `projects` and both `items` and `comments` have primary keys, say `id`, you can do a `LEFT` join of `projects` to the other tables and aggregate:

```
SELECT p.*,
       COUNT(DISTINCT i.id) items_count,
       COUNT(c.id) comments_count
FROM projects p
LEFT JOIN items i ON i.project_id = p.id
LEFT JOIN comments c ON c.item_id = i.id
GROUP BY p.id;
```

See a simplified [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/b9uVvX4o).